# Alternative to DISM for package removal on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, package-management, packages, dism

Is there any way - manual or automated - that allows for the removal of installation packages from Windows in offline mode (mounted wim) -- other than DISM?

Any automated solution should support the removal through WinApi and needs to support Windows 10. Package removal needs to be accurate the way DISM does it, so a simple solution of which files to delete is not enough. The registry and possibly other files need to be modified accordingly.

The only tools I know of that can do the job:

- Imagex: MS-Tool. Deprecated by DISM. Not supported on Win 10.
- PkgMgr: MS-Tool. Deprecated by DISM, but works on Windows 10.
- DISM: Microsoft's current package-managing tool.
- PowerShell's `Remove-AppxPackage` cmdlet: Only works on live system. Doesn't support mounted wim-files.

Is there any way (supported by MS) to remove packages manually in a proper fashion the way DISM does it or through other means like WinAPI or other tools?

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Thank you for the hints. Is there a way to move this question to softwarerecs or do I have to copy it over there myself? Regarding "enough information", I don't see how the question is unclear or too broad

Comment: The link says "It is not about ... asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation," Nothing to do with being too broad or unclear. You can flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: Your second link is all about questions being too broad or unclear. Why did you post it if that isn't a problem?

Comment: His second link is at Software Rec's... He's trying to point out what they require when asking a question *over there*. :)

Comment: The second link is to make sure you have a question that is acceptable to softwarerecs. I'm not a member over there so I cannot comment on their requirements. I told why it was off-topic for [su] **not** how it might be received on softwarerecs.

Comment: Why exactly can DISM not be used?

Comment: Alright, I modified the question asking for a general solution. In fact, I'd prefer a manual solution where I have to get down and dirty myself or by means of WinApi. This should be on topic. Thanks for the hints guys :)

Comment: @Ramhound Call it curiosity. Not important to the question, is it?

Comment: @Zerobinary99 - If I didn't think it was important I wouldn't have asked the question.  If its just curiosity, then the question is a theoretical question, and I want no part of it.  So now I know just to ignore it instead of investing time in researching and suggesting a solution.

Comment: @Ramhound `curiosity driven => theoretical question` my friend; how can you say that....

Comment: @Ramhound It's almost a given that people think they need to know the background story to a problem. Believe me, you don't need it. The solution will be put into action either by me using a suggested tool or writing a tool based on the information that people might give. However, if you don't have a shred of curiosity in you to learn about the inner workings of Windows then I want no part of your answer ;)

Comment: @Pat - Easily.  Unless there is a problem the author is trying to solve, then it is a theoretical problem, because otherwise there is a problem that is trying to solve.  I have found all to often theoretical problems are extremely difficult to solve, because the conditions of said question, are all to often changed after answering them.

Comment: @Zerobinary99 - Please don't indicate I don't need it.  You don't know how my brain works when solving problems.  As I said, if you don't have an actual problem, or don't want to indicate what that problem is.  You are welcome to do that, I just can't help you, since my brain works by connecting to my personal experiences and that requires knowing the reason you cannot use the DISM tool.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand and it's okay, but in this case it's really easy: How to remove packages manually or through other means. No other background needed.

Comment: @Zerobinary99 Okay, then the answer is: DISM is the way to remove packages.  Except you said that is not acceptable?  So okay, how about: remove every file by hand and edit the registry by hand.  That's probably not the best idea, but technically it's a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh852172.aspx) and [Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852152.aspx) are the Powershell 'equivalent' of DISM.  Peter Hahndorf has a discussion of the tools, and a list of their names on his blog, http://peter.hahndorf.eu/blog/WindowsFeatureViaCmd. The list that is supported by *-WindowsOptionalFeature is as follows:

```
ActiveDirectory-PowerShell 
ADCertificateServicesManagementTools 
ADCertificateServicesRole 
AdminUI 
Application-Server 
Application-Server-HTTP-Activation 
Application-Server-MSMQ-Activation 
Application-Server-Pipe-Activation 
Application-Server-TCP-Activation 
Application-Server-TCP-Port-Sharing 
Application-Server-WAS-Support 
Application-Server-WebServer-Support 
AppServer 
AS-Dist-Transaction 
AS-Ent-Services 
AS-Incoming-Trans 
AS-NET-Framework 
AS-Outgoing-Trans 
AS-WS-Atomic 
AuthManager 
BdeAducExtTool 
BiometricFramework 
BitLocker 
BitLocker-NetworkUnlock 
BitLocker-RemoteAdminTool 
Bitlocker-Utilities 
BITS 
BITSExtensions-AdminPack 
BITSExtensions-Upload 
BusScan-ScanServer 
CCFFilter 
CertificateEnrollmentPolicyServer 
CertificateEnrollmentServer 
CertificateServices 
CertificateServicesManagementTools 
ClientForNFS-Infrastructure 
CoreFileServer 
CoreFileServer-RSAT 
DamgmtTools 
DataCenterBridging 
Dedup-Core 
DesktopExperience 
DfsMgmt 
DFSN-Server 
DFSR-Infrastructure-ServerEdition 
DHCPServer 
DHCPServer-Tools 
DirectoryServices-ADAM 
DirectoryServices-ADAM-Tools 
DirectoryServices-AdministrativeCenter 
DirectoryServices-DomainController 
DirectoryServices-DomainController-Tools 
DirectoryServices-ISM-Smtp 
DirectPlay 
DNS-Server-Full-Role 
DNS-Server-Tools 
DSC-Service 
EnhancedStorage 
FailoverCluster-AdminPak 
FailoverCluster-AutomationServer 
FailoverCluster-CmdInterface 
FailoverCluster-FullServer 
FailoverCluster-Mgmt 
FailoverCluster-PowerShell 
FaxServiceConfigRole 
FaxServiceRole 
FileAndStorage-Services 
FileServerVSSAgent 
File-Services 
File-Services-Search-Service 
FRS-Infrastructure 
FSRM-Infrastructure 
FSRM-Infrastructure-Services 
FSRM-Management 
Gateway 
Gateway-UI 
HCAP-Server 
HCSRuntime 
HCSUI 
IAS NT Service 
IdentityServer-SecurityTokenService 
IIS-ApplicationDevelopment 
IIS-ApplicationInit 
IIS-ASP 
IIS-ASPNET 
IIS-ASPNET45 
IIS-BasicAuthentication 
IIS-CertProvider 
IIS-CGI 
IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication 
IIS-CommonHttpFeatures 
IIS-CustomLogging 
IIS-DefaultDocument 
IIS-DigestAuthentication 
IIS-DirectoryBrowsing 
IIS-FTPExtensibility 
IIS-FTPServer 
IIS-FTPSvc 
IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics 
IIS-HostableWebCore 
IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic 
IIS-HttpCompressionStatic 
IIS-HttpErrors 
IIS-HttpLogging 
IIS-HttpRedirect 
IIS-HttpTracing 
IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility 
IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication 
IIS-IPSecurity 
IIS-ISAPIExtensions 
IIS-ISAPIFilter 
IIS-LegacyScripts 
IIS-LegacySnapIn 
IIS-LoggingLibraries 
IIS-ManagementConsole 
IIS-ManagementScriptingTools 
IIS-ManagementService 
IIS-Metabase 
IIS-NetFxExtensibility 
IIS-NetFxExtensibility45 
IIS-ODBCLogging 
IIS-Performance 
IIS-RequestFiltering 
IIS-RequestMonitor 
IIS-Security 
IIS-ServerSideIncludes 
IIS-StaticContent 
IIS-URLAuthorization 
IIS-WebDAV 
IIS-WebServer 
IIS-WebServerManagementTools 
IIS-WebServerRole 
IIS-WebSockets 
IIS-WindowsAuthentication 
IIS-WMICompatibility 
InkAndHandwritingServices 
Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64 
IPAMClientFeature 
IPAMServerFeature 
iSCSITargetServer 
iSCSITargetServer-PowerShell 
iSCSITargetStorageProviders 
iSNS_Service 
KeyDistributionService-PSH-Cmdlets 
LegacyComponents 
Licensing 
Licensing-Diagnosis-UI 
Licensing-UI 
LightweightServer 
ManagementOdata 
MediaPlayback 
Microsoft-Hyper-V 
Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-Clients 
Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-PowerShell 
Microsoft-Hyper-V-Offline 
Microsoft-Hyper-V-Online 
Microsoft-Windows-Deployment-Services 
Microsoft-Windows-Deployment-Services-Admin-Pack 
Microsoft-Windows-Deployment-Services-Deployment-Server 
Microsoft-Windows-Deployment-Services-Legacy-SIS 
Microsoft-Windows-Deployment-Services-Transport-Server 
Microsoft-Windows-FCI-Client-Package 
Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy-ServerAdminTools-Update 
MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell 
MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellISE 
MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellRoot 
MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2 
Microsoft-Windows-ServerEssentials-ServerSetup 
Microsoft-Windows-Web-Services-for-Management-IIS-Extension 
MSMQ 
MSMQ-ADIntegration 
MSMQ-DCOMProxy 
MSMQ-HTTP 
MSMQ-Multicast 
MSMQ-RoutingServer 
MSMQ-Server 
MSMQ-Services 
MSMQ-Triggers 
MSRDC-Infrastructure 
MultipathIo 
NetFx3 
NetFx3ServerFeatures 
NetFx4 
NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45 
NetFx4ServerFeatures 
NetworkDeviceEnrollmentServices 
NetworkLoadBalancingFullServer 
NetworkLoadBalancingManagementClient 
NFS-Administration 
NIS 
NPAS-Role 
NPSManagementTools 
OEM-Appliance-OOBE 
OnlineRevocationServices 
OnlineRevocationServicesManagementTools 
P2P-PnrpOnly 
PeerDist 
PKIClient-PSH-Cmdlets 
Printing-AdminTools-Collection 
Printing-Client 
Printing-Client-Gui 
Printing-InternetPrinting-Client 
Printing-InternetPrinting-Server 
Printing-LPDPrintService 
Printing-LPRPortMonitor 
Printing-Server-Foundation-Features 
Printing-Server-Role 
Printing-XPSServices-Features 
PSync 
QWAVE 
RasCMAK 
RasRoutingProtocols 
RasServerAdminTools 
RemoteAccess 
RemoteAccessMgmtTools 
RemoteAccessPowerShell 
RemoteAccessServer 
RemoteAssistance 
Remote-Desktop-Services 
ResumeKeyFilter 
RightsManagementServices 
RightsManagementServices-AdminTools 
RightsManagementServicesManagementTools 
RightsManagementServices-Role 
RMS-Federation 
RPC-HTTP_Proxy 
RSAT 
RSAT-ADDS-Tools-Feature 
RSAT-AD-Tools-Feature 
RSAT-Hyper-V-Tools-Feature 
RSAT-NIS 
RSAT-RDS-Tools-Feature 
SBMgr-UI 
SearchEngine-Server-Package 
Security-SPP-Vmw 
ServerCore-Drivers-General 
ServerCore-EA-IME 
ServerCore-EA-IME-WOW64 
ServerCore-FullServer 
ServerCore-WOW64 
Server-Drivers-General 
Server-Drivers-Printers 
ServerForNFS-Infrastructure 
Server-Gui-Mgmt 
Server-Gui-Shell 
ServerManager-Core-RSAT 
ServerManager-Core-RSAT-Feature-Tools 
ServerManager-Core-RSAT-Role-Tools 
Server-Manager-RSAT-File-Services 
ServerMediaFoundation 
ServerMigration 
Server-Psh-Cmdlets 
Server-RSAT-SNMP 
ServicesForNFS-ServerAndClient 
SessionDirectory 
SimpleTCP 
SIS-Limited 
SMB1Protocol 
SMBBW 
SmbDirect 
SMBHashGeneration 
SmbWitness 
Smtpsvc-Admin-Update-Name 
Smtpsvc-Service-Update-Name 
SNMP 
Storage-Services 
TelnetClient 
TelnetServer 
TFTP 
TIFFIFilter 
TlsSessionTicketKey-PSH-Cmdlets 
UpdateServices 
UpdateServices-API 
UpdateServices-Database 
UpdateServices-RSAT 
UpdateServices-Services 
UpdateServices-UI 
UpdateServices-WidDatabase 
User-Interfaces-Infra 
VmHostAgent 
VolumeActivation-Full-Role 
WAS-ConfigurationAPI 
WAS-NetFxEnvironment 
WAS-ProcessModel 
WAS-WindowsActivationService 
WCF-HTTP-Activation 
WCF-HTTP-Activation45 
WCF-MSMQ-Activation45 
WCF-NonHTTP-Activation 
WCF-Pipe-Activation45 
WCF-Services45 
WCF-TCP-Activation45 
WCF-TCP-PortSharing45 
WebAccess 
Web-Application-Proxy 
WebEnrollmentServices 
WindowsFeedbackForwarder 
Windows-Identity-Foundation 
Windows-Internal-Database 
WindowsMediaPlayer 
WindowsPowerShellWebAccess 
WindowsServerBackup 
WindowsServerBackupSnapin 
WindowsStorageManagementService 
WINSRuntime 
WINS-Server-Tools 
WirelessNetworking 
WMISnmpProvider 
WorkFolders-Server 
WSS-Product-Package 
Xps-Foundation-Xps-Viewer
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Interesting! I wasn't aware of that possibility. I'll give it a shot :)

Comment: The link to Peter Hahndorf's site is a keeper. Unfortunately, the mentioned PowerShell cmdlets all rely on dism which can be seen on his webpage. Looks like dism and pkgmgr are the only MS-solutions regarding packages with the PowerShell cmdlets merely acting as front-ends to them.

Comment: I don't read his page that way, and it's probably not implemented that way.  I have never seen any first party PowerShell cmdlets that have external dependencies in that way.

Comment: Actually it is implemented that way. Check out the table in the "Platform Support" section. It clearly lists the sources for the cmdlets. I also gave it a shot and "Get-WindowsOptionalFeature" gave me a "check that DISM is properly installed" error: http://abload.de/img/dismerrorosuh6.png

Comment: Well...alrighty then.  That's an odd choice on their part.

Comment: @Mr.Smythe - If you understand what PowerShell is, it isn't that odd, in the slightest.