# Enable "Graphics Tools for Windows 10" feature offline?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, directx, dism, windows-10-v1709

I am trying to build a Visual Studio 2015 project requiring **[Graphics Tools for Windows 10](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/31/visual-studio-2015-and-graphics-tools-for-windows-10/)** as enabled feature.

I've [read](https://www.tenforums.com/printthread.php?t=29258) that this could be installed (=enabled) using Windows 10 UI named "optional features" in "apps & features". In my case the UI is infinitely loading, since there is no internet connection (it is true)

I don't see any download link of such feature. Additionally, in the latest Win10 Pro installation (1709), i don't see such feature (and anything "graphic") when using command like

```
DISM .. /Get-Features
```

**How can i install these tools the command line way or using a file** (or using windows image iso)?

Note. An example list of features listed by DISM is in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/970094/alternative-to-dism-for-package-removal-on-windows-10?rq=1), so there is not "graphics tool".

Comment: @Ramhound its 2015. but as far as i understand, graphics tools enable some debugging features of directx api, which are not related to an actual vs version

Comment: Only specific versions of Visual Studio support this Graphics Tools package.  So it’s relevant.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i install these tools the command line way or using a file (or
>   using windows image ISO)?

I do not believe this to be possible.

> How can i install these tools, and preferably offline (or using
>   windows image ISO)?

The `Windows Graphics Tools` is a component of the `Windows 10 SDK`, it is not, a component of Windows itself.  You can download the `Windows 10 SDK for Fall Creators Update` [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=859887)

> Visual Studio 2015 also supports development on Windows 10 and has new
>   features targeting Windows 10 development. The Visual Studio Tools for
>   Windows 10, which became available this week, provides additional
>   Windows 10 specific tools, libraries and header files. It also
>   automatically configures the Windows Graphics Tools optional feature.
>   Alternatively, if you desire all the Windows 10 tools, you can install
>   the Windows 10 Standalone SDK.

[Visual Studio 2015 and Graphics Tools for Windows 10](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/31/visual-studio-2015-and-graphics-tools-for-windows-10/)

Comment: something strange with this component of windows sdk, since i have it installed already. ill text back